# Select multiple elements with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

Since I could not find an explained example elsewhere, I share my findings as a Q&A.

Consider this list of pupils (`pupils.xml`):

```
<pupils>
    <pupil>
        <firstName>Adam</firstName>
        <lastName>Amith</lastName>
        <birthDate>2000-01-01</birthDate>
    </pupil>
    <pupil>
        <firstName>Berta</firstName>
        <lastName>Bmith</lastName>
        <birthDate>2000-01-02</birthDate>
    </pupil>
    <pupil>
        <firstName>Caesar</firstName>
        <lastName>Cmith</lastName>
        <birthDate>2000-01-03</birthDate>
    </pupil>
    <pupil>
        <firstName>Doris</firstName>
        <lastName>Dmith</lastName>
        <birthDate>2000-01-04</birthDate>
    </pupil>
</pupils>
```

How can I select two subattributes of each pupil to get a list like this:

```
Adam Amith
Berta Bmith
Caesar Cmith
Doris Dmith
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command to get this is

```
xmlstarlet select -T -t -m "//pupil" -v "firstName" -o " " -v "lastName" -n pupils.xml
```

and brings:

```
Adam Amith
Berta Bmith
Caesar Cmith
Doris Dmith
```

- `-T` switches the output to `text`
- `-t -m "//pupil" -v "firstName" -o " " -v "lastName" -n` defines a *template*

  - `-m "//pupil"` *matches* every `pupil` node
  - `-v "firstName"` *prints* the value of the `firstName` subnode (subnode of currently matched node)
  - `-o " "` *prints* a blank
  - `-v "lastName"` (see above)
  - `-n` prints a *newline*
- `pupils.xml` provides the input file

[The documentation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416) provides even more advanced parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `concat()` here:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m //pupil -v "concat(.//firstName ,' ',.//lastName)" -n pupils.xml
```

with the same output.